# JLabel centering

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, layout-manager, null-layout-manager

I have a `JFrame` which contains a `JPanel`, in the `JPanel` I have multiple `JTextField` and `JLabel` components. My text fields are already centered by setting their bounds, but how can I center my label's texts horizontally and change the vertical location of each label? Or how can I use `FontMetrics` to get the string width so I can center them manually by setting their bounds?

Comment: In Swing, you typically don't set the bounds but instead use a `LayoutManager`. See [this guide](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for an overview of the different layout managers

Comment: Provide ASCII art or a simple drawing of the intended GUI at initial size and when it is given more width and height (to show how extra space should be assigned.)

Comment: BTW - if the GUI requires paired labels and textfields something like seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6kpas.png) we might use a `GroupLayout` or `GridBagLayout`.

Comment: I think that code ([mre] ) would have been clearer and shorter than the attempt to describe it.